# How to apply AWK to a directory path?

Tags: awk

I have this command:

```
Folder=./GAS/NNN_/Neutral
awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}' $Folder
```

But I got: `awk: read error (Is a directory)`

I have tried:

```
awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}' $(Folder)
awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}' $($Folder)
awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}' $(echo $Folder)
```

And I got the same response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of awk is either `awk 'awk script' input_file` or `input_stream | awk 'awk script'`. You are trying to pass the variable as a file name and since the variable's value is a directory, awk tries to open that directory as a file and fails.

So, you either need to print out the value and then pass that to `awk` (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) for why I am using `printf` here):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$Folder" | awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}'
NNN_
```

Or you can use a [here string](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html):

```
$ awk -F / '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$Folder"
NNN_
```